# Why program opened with OllyDbg 2 isn't paused at start?

Tags: ollydbg, breakpoint, entry-point

There is one thing that I still can’t understand about Olly.

I have a sample (an .SCR file) which I’m trying to analyze. When I open it with Olly 1.10, the file is loaded and its execution is paused just at the start.

But when I open it with Olly 2.01, it is loaded AND executed immediately, so it closes processes, breaks Olly, VM, etc… I’ve tried to select different options in “Options”->”Debugging”->”Start”, but noticed no difference at all.

How can I make Olly 2.01 behave like Olly 1.10 so I can step over the instructions from the very beginning?

UPD.: I've tried to uncheck the "Unpack SFX module authomatically" checkbox, but the process is still executing after opening.

P.S. I’ve uploaded the sample here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=91057886723949836306
IT IS A VIRUS SAMPLE, so the archive is encrypted with the password "infected".

Comment: See [Why does Olly 2.01 fail to break at the module EP?](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/8288/1562)

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies. Unfortunately, the process doesn't seem to stop at EP even after unchecking the "Unpack SFX module authomatically" checkbox. :(

Comment: @Alex, does the program contain TLS callbacks?

Comment: Many thanks to everyone who answered! It seems like there was a problem with my VM (e. g. opening Sysinternals Autoruns in Olly leaded to same problems as opening malware sample). Enabling hardware virtualization support on host seems to fix the problem. Everything is OK now even at default settings (auto-unpack SFX and break at EP of the main module). Thanks for the help!